# Stash : Conditional Content

Tags: expressionengine, expressionengine-stash

First off, a caveat ... I am brand new to Stash. I've heard a lot about it but this is my first time actually playing with it. I get the concept, but am having a hard time figuring this one thing out.

I have a main "wrapper" file and everything within that wrapper stays the same. I would like the option however, to be able to toggle the sidebar on and off if I need to.

I wouldn't think I would need a totally separate layout wrapper would I?

Is there a way to use a boolean variable within stash? (e.g. 2col=TRUE) or am I thinking about it wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use one wrapper for every template. It'll contain an `{exp:stash:get name="content"}` tag, like yours, which contains the only variable content within.

In my individual templates, I embed the wrapper at the beginning using a regular EE embed ie. `{embed="includes/wrapper"}`.
Then I stash the content to be inserted into the wrapper using the `{exp:stash:set name="content"}` tag.
This seems like what you're doing anyway.

If I want to conditionally show a sidebar, I might just pass a variable into the embed.
eg. `{embed="includes/wrapper" show_sidebar="yes"}`

In my wrapper I would do this:

```
{if embed:show_sidebar}
  Sidebar stuff.
{/if}
```

Comment: I like that solution. Never thought of using embed variables, in the wrapper embed. Genius.

Comment: This same concept can be accomplished using Stash embeds in the dev branch. I don't use any EE embeds anymore in-favor of Stash embeds. They are totally awesome - just grab the dev branch of Stash.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I haven't familiarized myself with stash embeds yet. If they can perform the same task, then that would be an even better solution.

Comment: Cool solution, definitely a "why didn't I think of that" moment there :)

Answer (score 4):

Generally what I'd do here is setup multiple Stash gets within the wrapper. Then in your individual templates you can set both the sidebar and the main content area. For parts where you might be repeating content, like the opening and closing divs of a sidebar, you can always  drop some snippets inside the stash.

You can also use `exp:stash:not_empty` [[docs]](https://github.com/croxton/Stash#expstashnot_empty) to wrap around the div or container for your sidebar within the wrapper.